# Log4J throws illegal char <:> exception while processing Appender File in Springboot WebApp

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am using Log4J along with Springboot in my J2EE based WebApp.

It throws ***illegal char <:> exception while processing Appender File***.

**Log4J version: 2.11.1**

The logger properties in my application.properties file are as below

```
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.file=log\\web.log
```

I understand that it's because of the character **colon ':'** , but even after trying out different patterns, I still get the same error message.
I don't know where the `${sys:LOG_PATH}` part is coming from and how to fix this.

Can someone please help.

Attaching the error stack trace as well.

[image: stack trace]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you try log/web.log instead of log\\web.log

Comment: @KemalKaplan sure, I'll try. But it's creating that file properly and no issues in that. Issue is while the rolling appender kicks in.

Comment: Maybe it looks for log4j.appender.rollingFile.File property and falls back to sys property if it is missing...

Comment: Just a note: Please do not post logs, traces etc. as picture. Copy the text and format the text as code using the code format option of the editor. This way people can easily copy parts of the logs etc.